# Is it possible to use server-side events to notify an iOS user despite my app not running, without using Apple Push Notification Service?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, server-sent-events

I am considering using EventSource (server-sent events) to send notifications to my iOS App users, instead of APNS. This is great when app is active, but is it possible to ensure these users receive my messages when my app is not currently running on their device? Or is the only way to do this APNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need your events to arrive in real-time (like a messaging system), then APNS is probably your best bet. APNS is the only way to send realtime messages from a server to your app. However, it is wise to know that there are downsides to push notifications.

If you don't care about real-time events (not a messaging system), or if it's okay if you get the events a bit delayed, you can use background fetching to periodically poll your server for new events.

Objc.io has a great article discussing some of these: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html

Comment: I don't think APNS is the only way. If the client opens an SSE connection with the server, the server can sent notifications in real time. I need to know if there is a way to get my SSE service onto the user's iPhone and have it run whether the app is quit or running (background or otherwise).

Comment: @user2817034 - brimizer is correct. Once the app is closed or suspended then it cannot run anymore code to get to your server for notifications. The basic limit put by iOS is 10 min max for running any additional code after app is closed by the user. Fetch is your only other option.